# What is solution of this integration

Tags: calculus

I have a question about the following integration
$\int_0^T \frac{\partial f(x+t)}{\partial x} dt$

Is it equal to F(x+T)-F(x)

Comment: Why use partial derivative symbols? Did you mean $f(x,t)$?

Comment: no it is f(x+t)

Answer (score 0):

It equals $f(x+T) - f(x)$.
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[f(x+t)\right] = f'(x+t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left[f(x+t)\right]
$$
then use the fundamental theorem of calculus on the integral.

Comment: I'm not the asker. How can you take two different partial derivatives and have the same answer?

Comment: @O.VonSeckendorff If it helps, consider the function $g(x,t) = f(x + t)$. Then for this particular function, it happens to be true that $\partial g/\partial x = \partial g/\partial t$.